# Authorization Scopes To Get Follower Count From Tiktok

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, tiktok

Authorization Scopes To Get Follower Count From Tiktok
The Tiktok developer API documentation only lists three sets of scopes that an application can request:

- video.list
- user.info.basic
- share.sound.create

Unfortunately, the user.info.basic scope only allows you to see some really basic info (not even a profile URL!). Are there any "hidden" scopes that I can request that would allow me to get more information about a user? Specifically, I'd like to be able to get at least their follower count, and ideally also the profile url. Such a scope definitely does exist; if you make a request to /user/info/, and you include a field which doesn't exist, you simply get no data. However, if you ask for the field "follower_count", you get an error that user.info.basic doesn't grant sufficient permissions.

Comment: I had the same problem. couldn't find any answer from tiktok's documentation. ended up looking into tiktok's network and found this endpoint. `https://www.tiktok.com/api/user/detail/?uniqueId=<any_display_name>&msToken=<token>`. There you can get  the avatar urls and `followerCount`. Not the exact solution but there's nothing else I can find to solve my problem.

Comment: It seems their API v2 now has `profile_deep_link` on the user/info endpoint.